# NetBeans save edited .jar

Tags: java, netbeans, edit, libraries

I am currently using a library for "Notify My Android". The library is using an outdated URL so i tried to change it. I attached the source file and now I can edit the code. Before attaching the source file it just said "compiled code". But when i save it it does not seem to save the changes. It is still using the old URL. Also the change I made is underlined in blue. I hope somebody knows how to make the .jar to accept my changes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

it's highly discouraged to modify jars you depend on simply because if you ever want to upgrade versions you'd need to modify the new jar you are looking for.

In those situations you have these options:

1. if it is an open source project, contribute to the project and correct the URL
2. try and set the property from your code (this may not be possible in certain situations)
3. try and extend the class you're trying to use and set the URL on the property you need (like the previous one, it may not be possible to do this)
4. this should be your last resource: create your own project (from the original jar), make the changes you require, package it up and add it to you app.